# Java concurrent hashMap retrieval

Tags: java, multithreading

`ConcurrentHashMap` documentation says:

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)

But I am not able to understand how retrieval operation do not block with update/remove operation for same key ?

"an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key"

that sort of indicate that concurrent hash map has some way create sequence for read/update/remove operations on same key. But that mean read operations are blocked by update/remove operations.

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: May be try some code and clear your doubts; otherwise its just more theory. Do you know what happens-before means (Oracle's Java tutorials has an example and explanation of it)?

Comment: Another suggestion:  try to think an example application where you might want to use this collection. And, how it can be useful in a particular scenario or solve a problem.

Comment: Think of an example application where you are using a `HashMap` and applying sychronization or locks (`java.util.concurrent.locks` package) to read and update the collection. Perhaps using a `ConcurrentHashMap`, instead of a `HashMap` and sychronization, in such case may be a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to java's tutorial on happen-before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But I am not able to understand how retrieval operation do not block with update/remove operation for same key ?

First of all, "how" it does it is an implementation detail.  If you really want / need to understand "how", you need to look at the source code.  It is available from various places.

But what this is actually saying is that:

- `get` doesn't block, and
- what you see when you do a `get` is the value from the *most recently **completed** `put` operation* for that key.

So if you do a `get` while a `put` is in progress, you may see the value from the previous `put`.

Note that the 2nd bullet point explains (implicitly) *why* it is possible for `get` to be non-blocking.  There is no need for `get(42)` to wait for a  `put(42, value)` that is currently in progress to finish ... since the `get` call is allowed to return the previous value.

TL;DR - there is no need to block.

---

The stuff about "*happens before*" relationships is relating this to the semantics of the Java Memory Model.  This may be important if you are doing a deep analysis of your code.  But for a shallow understanding of what `ConcurrentHashMap` does, you can ignore it.

> ... that sort of indicate that concurrent hash map has some way create sequence for read/update/remove operations on same key.

It doesn't imply that at all.  But to understand what the statement you quoted really means, you need a need a good understanding of the Java Memory Model.  And I don't think it is feasible to convey that to you in a StackOverflow Q&A.  I recommend you take a few **hours** to read and understand the JMM ... by reading the JLS.  Then, do it again.

This is NOT stuff where an intuitive understanding is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted to implement some sort of custom concurrent trie and wanted to know how ConcurrentHashMap keep read unblocked. Looks like might not be so simple as I assumed :)