# ConcurrentHashMap Behavior and Questions

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrenthashmap

I have 4 threads - 2 of the thread does update and 2 of the thread does read on the concurrentHashMap. The code is as follow:

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private static final Object lock = new Object();
```

Thread 1 and Thread 2's run method (key and value is a string)

```
synchronized (lock) {
    if (!myHashMap.containsKey(key)) {
        myHashMap.put(key, value);
    } else {
        String value = myHashMap.get(key)
        // do something with the value
        myHashMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Thread 3 and Thread 4's run method does the print

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : myHashMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("key, " + key + " value " + value);
}
```

Is there any issue with the above usage of ConcurrenHashMap code?
Because when I read the Javadoc and search the web, I found the following claim:

1. This class is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety **but not on its synchronization details.** (Note - I understand the print thread result might not be the most recent result, but that is ok as long as the update thread does things correctly.)
2. There is also some claim over the website that says the same Iterator cannot be used for 2 or more different thread. So I am wondering if the print method uses the same Iterator in 2 thread above. And why we cannot use the same Iterator in 2 different threads?

As for the requirement, I want concurrent read without blocking that is why I choose the ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: "Is there any issue with the above code?" I don't think we can answer that without knowing exactly what you want to do and how you're doing it. Your code snippet is too vague. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for instructions on how to make a better code example.

Comment: Updated the code. Do something with the value just means computing the value.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes  Well I need to make sure the update thread is locked so only 1 thread can do the update other one has to wait.

Comment: You just need to assume the update thread can only be atomic run for all the code inside.

Comment: You're undermining the whole purpose of CHM by using it under an external lock. Use the atomic `merge()` instead.

Comment: I don't think we can really suggest a `compute` or `merge` without knowing what "do something with the value" actually does.

Comment: Remember the whole purpose of using CHM, in this case, is to achieve non blocking read/print.

Comment: I recently ran into a thread with a similar post; may be this will clarify your doubts: [Java concurrent hashMap retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219103/java-concurrent-hashmap-retrieval)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the if else block you can use the putIfAbsent method from the concurrent hashmap and second thing you should not use the external locking in concurrent hashmap.

Comment: The thing is I cannot use the build in putIfAbsent method due to the complexity of the computation. And why shouldn't we use external lock? Is there any unexpected behavior when using external lock? or it just due to performance? I bet the performance can't be any worst than using a Hashtable which block even on read thread.